# What is the equivalent of IOS [application.window makeKeyAndVisible] in Android?

Tags: android, ios

In IOS, the application window can render another UIViewController through the following.

```
application.viewController = (a new UIViewController)
application.window.rootViewController = application.viewController;
[application.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

What is the equivalent in Android? I know that intents are used for firing new activities. Are intents right way to get the above IOS behavior in Android?

Comment: You might wish to explain in greater detail what "render another UIViewController" means, using general computer programming terms.

Comment: @CommonsWare My assumption is that someone would already know what the attached IOS code means and also has enough knowledge of android to answer the question.